# Is there an SSTP (Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol) server available for Linux?

Tags: linux, vpn, ssl, https, sstp

I'm interested in installing an SSTP VPN server on one of my Linux VPSes somehow, but as far as I can see there are only servers available built in to Windows Server.

Is this correct or have I just not found one?

Comment: Why would you even want to? SSL 3.0 has been broken for a very long time.

Answer (score 2):

At this moment there is no SSTP server realization for *nix, only [client](http://sstp-client.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: And whats the client?

Comment: Look at link in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Only http://www.softether.org/ as of the time of this posting it seems.